# Service not running on IIS 6.0 of Server because of http error 404.3 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, iis-6

i have two projects in a solution of asp.net c# web application. One of them is a .asmx service. I have added the reference of my service in my second project. I have published it and deployed it on my system on IIS 6. That works fine on my system. But when i deploy it on the IIS of server, It gives an error of "HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map."

Comment: it says that there is no end point. Although there is a end point in my second project related to the service. In the address of end point, i've simply put the web path off service like this "http://localhost/datafromsap.asmx".

Comment: i'm just publishing second project, not the first one of service. I've added the reference of service in second project. What can be the issue?

Comment: Are you able to browse your service (asmx) ?